# iOS error: "Protocol qualifiers without "id" is archaic" when adopting protocol in a category

Tags: ios, protocols, objective-c-category

I'm trying to make a category adopt a protocol, and I'm having a problem with what seems like a simple thing.

The interface declaration is:

```
@interface UIView (UIViewCategory) <DesiredProtocol>
```

And I was assuming the implementation declaration should be the same:

```
@implementation UIView (UIViewCategory) <DesiredProtocol>
```

But this gets a yellow warning in XCode, with the message: "Protocol qualifiers without 'id' is archaic".

So should the declaration be:

```
@implementation UIView (UIViewCategory) id<DesiredProtocol>
```

??

I can't find reference for this specific issue. Much thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the protocol list on an @implementation block, whether it's a category or not.

```
@implementation UIView (UIViewCategory)
...
@end
```

Comment: +1 right. it's omitted on the `@implementation`, just like a regular `@interface`+`@implementation` pair

Answer (score 0):

This is how you declare a protocol

```
@protocol ProtocolName <NSObject>

//protocol methods

@end
```

Later it's property

```
@interface ProtocolClass: NSObject
{...}
@end 
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <ProtocolName> delegate;
//Synthesize it!
```

And then you adopt it

```
@interface ClassThatAdoptsProtocol: NSObject <ProtocolName>{...}
```